# Look up a key in a chain of Python dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, lookup, chain

Is there a built-in way in Python to look up a key `k` in a `dict` `d` and, if the key is not present, look it up instead in another `dict` `e`?

Can this be extended to an arbitrarily long chain of `dict`s `d` => `e` => `f` => ...?

Comment: Is it linear search between the dicts? like it always will look d first, then e, then f..

Comment: @Vinny - yes, I would like to look at the dicts in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

d = ChainMap({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 22}, {'c': 3})
print(d['c'])
print(d['b'])
```

This would output:

```
3
2
```

Notice that the lookup for key `'b'` was satisfied by the first dictionary in the map and the remaining dicts where not searched.

`ChainMap` was introduced in Python 3.3

Comment: If you need to support Python2.7, then you can use the backport: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chainmap

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python < 3.3, `ChainMap` isn't available.

This is less elegant, but works:

```
a = {1: 1, 2: 2}
b = {3: 3, 4: 4}

list_dicts = [a, b]

def lookup(key):
    for i in list_dicts:
        if key in i:
            return i[key]
    raise KeyError

lookup(1) # --> 1
lookup(4) # --> 4
```

You add all the dicts to a list, and use a method to look over them.

Answer (score 1):

May be like below:

```
if k in d:
    pass
elif k in e:
    pass
elif k in f:
    ...
```