# Check if the values inside a list is empty if so it should get the value from the above dictionary values

Tags: python, json

In the JSON file there is a list of dictionary if the list value is given empty then it should get the value from the main dictionary if the main dictionary is also empty then generate an error message.

Instead of using a common flag, it should get values either from list or above dictionary.

```
{
    "Demo": {

        "Common_Src_Trg":true,
        "Source_db":true,
        "Source_Host": "192.168.0.121",
        "Source_UserName": "testuser",
        "Source_Port": "3306",

        "Table_Details": [
                          {
                          "Source_db":true,
                          "Source_Host": "192.168.0.121",
                          "Source_UserName": "testuser",
                          "Source_Port": "3306",
                          }
                          ]
    }

}
```

```py
if dataSource["Demo"]["Common_Src_Trg"]:
    if dataSource["Demo"]["Source_dbConn"]:
        source_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = dataSource["Demo"]["Source_dbHost"],
            username = dataSource["Demo"]["Source_dbUserName"],
            port = dataSource["Demo"]["Source_dbport"])
        print("source_connection_SUCCESS")

    else:
        # src_conn
        if dataSource["Demo"]["Table_Details"][con]["Source_db"]:
            src_conn = mysql.connector.connect(
               host = dataSource["Demo"]["Table_Details"]["Source_Host"],
               username = dataSource["Demo"]["Table_Details"]["Source_UserName"],
               port = dataSource["Demo"]["Table_Details"]["Source_Port"])
        print("src_DB_conn_SUCCESS ",con)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Show what you tried (code) in the question

Comment: @JeremyHue. Like if I need to get the value from the table details **Source_Host : **and in case that value is empty , it should get the value from the **Source_dbHost: **if  that value is also empty it should return an error message like **Host not found check the son file**

Comment: @MichaelButscher as of now I gave a flag at the top called common=true then it gets the vale from the top else if false it gets the value from the list , but I am trying not to use the common flag i

Comment: @JeremyHue  any method that could solve this.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. The head and list of dicts mostly use different keys - e.g. `Source_dbHost`, `Source_dbUserName` versus `Source_Host`, `Source_username` - making it unclear when to use which fallback. Given the different capitalisation, there seems to be no direct translation from one to the other, either. Your example code already fails at the very first line.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so you mean that I should make the key name same ??

Comment: If they mean the same, then yes they should be the same. If they do not mean the same, explain how one can fall back to using the other.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi okey once done that ... how do I make it fall back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Look up a key in a chain of Python dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644641/look-up-a-key-in-a-chain-of-python-dicts)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi brother I don't think you got my point. Its simple if the dictionary inside the Table_Details value is empty then its should check the parent dictionary to get the value .  if possible please give an example

Comment: This is yet another slightly different requirement. So far, you have mentioned three scenarios: 1) nested dictionary is empty, use entire top-level dictionary, 2) nested dictionary misses one key/value, access key/value from top-level dictionary, 3) nested dictionary has key but value is empty, access key/value from top-level dictionary. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a dictionary is empty you need to read by layers of `{}`, taking the key value and comparing the content shuld work just fine.

```
D = {
    "Demo": {
        "key_a": "true",
        "key_b": "",
        }
    }


def check(dictionary):
    flag = True
    for i in dictionary:
        if dictionary[i] == '':
            print('Missing: {0}'.format(i))
            flag = False
    return flag


if check(D["Demo"]):
    print("Complite")
else:
    print("Incomplite")
```

But with sql insted of cheching each value you can catch the error with the funtion `try` 
and print the error ( if you dont know how the exception is named leave it empty, it will catch everyting).

```
try:
    mysql.connector.connect()
except mysql.connector.errors as error:
    print(error)
```